# Loading an image stored in the folder which is inside web folder using jsp

Tags: image, jsp

I have a web project and I have uploadedImage inside the web folder of the project. I want to load an image which is inside uploadedImage folder. Im deploying the war file in Tomcat server. I coded as follows

```
            <a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-default bg-light-gray">Upload a new Image</a>

        </div>

    </div>
    <%
        String fname = (String) request.getAttribute("name");
   String pathImage = "C://bimla//Dev//java//OCRSystem//WebContent//uploadedImage//";
    System.out.print("uploaded image"+fname);
        session.setAttribute("filename", fname);
        fname = fname + ".jpg";
        System.out.println("with extension"+fname);
        String path = "";
        if (request.getAttribute("name") != null) {
            path = request.getAttribute("name").toString();
        }
    %>

    <div class="row">
        <div  id = "display" class="col-lg-8 center-block modal-content">
        <img src="C:\\bimla\\Dev\\java\\OCRSystem\\WebContent\\uploadedImage\<%=fname%>" width="600" height="400"/>


        </div>

    </div>
```

But image is not displayed. When copy paste the path in the browser image displays correctly. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your page is loaded through http (I assume). Nowadays luckily there is quite some boundary that websites (e.g. everything coming in through http) can't address your local filesystem (e.g. URLs starting with `file:///` or `C:/`)

On a related note, don't build a web application that allows to upload files right into the webapplication's folder. This is bad for

- security
- backup
- updates
- redeployment

Rather upload to some other location and include a download servlet.

Side note: you *might* need duplicate `\\` to escape backslashes in various cases (HTML has no such limitations though), but you definitely only need single `/` if you choose to use slash as the directory separator (this is not your problem though)

Quick Fix: You should load the image through http. Assuming that the image is in the same web application as your JSP, using `<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/uploadImages/<%=fname%>">` (or similar - you don't provide enough information for a definitive statement) will load the image through http. Note that this only quickfixes your current problem. The proper fix will be to upload the images to a folder (or database or storage) outside of your web application's directory - for the reasons given above.

Comment: Although I remove double lines, it still doesn't show the image

Comment: That was just a side note. The main information is in mixing http content with file content: It doesn't work.